# Cannot stop button click event when i click in another button

Tags: javascript, events

When i click in "A+" more times than possible to change and then i click on "A-", the font-size increases instead of decreasing in first click.
How can i stop this event during click in another button?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var fontSize = 16;
  /* Increase Text */
  $("#increase-text").click(function(){
    if(fontSize >= 24) {
      return false;
   }else {
    $(".main-content").css("font-size", fontSize + "px");
     fontSize = fontSize + 1;
     console.log('+ ' + fontSize);
    }

  });

  /* Decrease Text */
  $("#decrease-text").click(function(){

    if(fontSize <= 10) {
   return false;
    }else {

   $(".main-content").css("font-size", fontSize + "px");
   fontSize = fontSize - 1;
   console.log('+ ' + fontSize);
   }
  });
  /* Default */
  $("#normal-text").click(function(){
    var fontSize = 16;
    $(".main-content").css("font-size", fontSize + "px");
    $('body').removeClass("contrast-white");
    $('body').removeClass("contrast-black");
  });
  /* Contrast Black */
  $("#contrast-b").click(function(){
    $('body').addClass("contrast-black");
    $('body').removeClass("contrast-white");
  });

  /* Contrast White */
  $("#contrast-w").click(function(){
     $('body').addClass("contrast-white");
     $('body').removeClass("contrast-black");
  });
});
```

```css
.controllSize a {
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: 0.5s ease-in-out
}
.controllSize {
    text-align: right
}
.controllSize .boxCtrl {
    display: inline-block
}
.controllSize a {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 14px
}
.controllSize a:hover {
    background-color: #c8c8c8;
    border-color: #000
}
.controllSize a#contrast-b {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.controllSize a#contrast-w {
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: bold;
}

/* Constrast White */
html body.contrast-white {
    background-color: #fff !important;
    color: #000 !important;
    box-shadow: none;
}

/* Constrast Black */
html body.contrast-black {
    background-color: #000 !important;
    color: #fff !important;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="controllSize">
 <div class="boxCtrl" style="font-size: 23.5px;"> 
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="decrease-text" title="Diminuir fonte">A-</a> 
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="increase-text" title="Aumentar fonte">A+</a> 
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="normal-text"   title="Fonte normal">A</a> 
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="contrast-b"   title="Contraste preto/branco">A</a> 
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="contrast-w"   title="Contraste branco/preto" >A</a>
 </div>
 <div class="main-content">
  <h1>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed accumsan porta nisl id ullamcorper. Pellentesque lobortis, neque ac suscipit feugiat, justo eros egestas magna, ut euismod dolor orci vel turpis. Maecenas in odio non justo consequat luctus quis quis elit. Integer ultrices lorem sit amet libero luctus, ac aliquam augue scelerisque. Sed ultrices aliquet metus id aliquam. Duis elementum turpis ut eros rutrum, vel venenatis leo venenatis. Phasellus condimentum viverra massa, quis dignissim sem accumsan dictum. Nullam vulputate dolor eget sollicitudin tincidunt.</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the order of your operations - first change the font size and then change the css -

```
fontSize = fontSize + 1;
$(".main-content").css("font-size", fontSize + "px");
```

also in the decrease text function.

I would also change the normal-text to not redeclare the fontSize variable

```
fontSize = 16;
```